# HTML/JS - Create a "double-level" of anchors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, fullpage.js

im developing a one-page-based website. The main page has vertical scrolling through a menu and sections/data-anchors. Now i'd need to put in one section an horizontal slider. To be more specific, i have `div` which is filled by a php script with one or more tables. If one table is enough for all informations, no problems. But if one table is not enough, i'd need to dynamically create an horizontal slider into the `div`, where each slide is another `div`with a table inside. I have already done it (im not sure i want to post the code, i'd need to much lines). My problem is split the anchors of the main page with the anchors of the horizontal slider.

Currently, im able to get XXX tables printed by a php script into an horizontal slider. The problem is that, if i want to go at "page 5" of the slider, clicking on the link i get the browser searching for a "page 5" into the main page **instead of into the horizontal slider**

Hence, How i can split, keep separeted, the anchors of the main page and the anchors of the slider?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Im trying to use FullPage horizontal slider, since my main page too is based on FullPage.js. Im echoing from a php script both the `slide div and the table div` . The result structure is as follow:

```
<div class="section fp-section fp-table active" data-anchor="ineedslides" id="section1" style="height: 261px; padding: 3em 0px 10px;">
    <div class="fp-tableCell" style="height:199px;">

        <div class="wrapper style1">
                    <header class="major">
                        <h2>Hello</h2>
                        <p>I need a dynamic table below here!!</p>
                    </header>
            <div class="fp-slides" id="tables">

                <div class="fp-slidesContainer" style="width: 900%; top: 46%;"> 

                    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1" style="width: 11.111111111111%; float: left; top: 46%; position: relative;">
                        <ul></ul>
                        <div class="table-wrapper" style="top: 46%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2" style="width: 11.111111111111%; float: left; top: 46%; position: relative;">
                        <ul></ul>
                        <div class="table-wrapper" style="top: 46%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide3" style="width: 11.111111111111%; float: left; top: 46%; position: relative;">
                        <ul></ul>
                        <div class="table-wrapper" style="top: 46%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide4" style="width: 11.111111111111%; float: left; top: 46%; position: relative;">
                        <ul></ul>
                        <div class="table-wrapper" style="top: 46%;">               
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

well..now clicking on one of the links to navigate into the slides, i get "page mysite/#tables/slideX doesnt exist"..
well.. if i try to set links like "mysite#tables/slideX" (**so without the forward slash**), i get no more errors but nothing happen. Where am i wrong with the creation of the sections/slides? how i can get a link like this http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage/2 with the forward slash, which splits the sections links and page links?

thanks

Comment: Let the code speak... any answer will be a guess...

Comment: ok sorry. check my edit. thanks

Comment: i'd need alvaro, the creator of FullPage.js :)

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 separate problems here.

**The main anchors href:**

Imagine you have this

```
<a href="#section_one">Go to section one</a>
<a href="#section_two">Go to section two</a>

<div id="section_one">this is section one</div>
<div id="section_two">this is section two</div>
```

When you click the anchors, the document will move to the respective "id". So if you are in the same page, you don't need to add "host.com/#section_one".

But you could do it. Check this link

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/#the-view-layer

It will take you straight to that id : the-view-layer

If you check the source code, you'll find an element with that id right on top where it landed:

```
<span id="the-view-layer"></span>
```

If you were on that page already, a simple

```
<a href="#the-view-layer">The view Layer</a>
```

would be sufficient to take you there.

**The forward slash:**

The forward slash before the # works because there is a url rewriting of some sort.. The same way that, if you have

```
your_host.com/index.php
```

you can reach the same page by simply writing

```
your_host.com/
```

this works with index pages

Now if that page has a section_one, you could go straight to it by using

```
your_host.com/index.php#section_one
```

or

```
your_host.com/#section_one
```

You could even put that in an anchor href on an external page

```
<a href="your_host.com/#section_one">Go to my host index page, on section one</a>
```

Now lets add something after the #

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/#the-view-layer/fsdfdgd/fsdgdf

Notice that it goes to the same page, even after adding those extra bits after the #. The server cannot read anything after the hash, so it loads the correct page, but this time, the browser wont take you to that section, since there's is no id named "the-view-layer/fsdfdgd/fsdgdf"

So the problem with the forward slash is simple - either you use a index.php or you have to use url rewriting or a framework that does that for you by naming the urls

eg:

youhost.com/users/list/

**The secondary anchors href:**

So sections will have id's like section_one/slide_one

I made this really quick and you might have to tweak it if you have some sort of js slider plugin, but you get the point:

```
<div id="header">
    <a class="main_links" href="#section_one/slide_one">1-1</a>
    <a class="main_links" href="#section_one/slide_two">1-2</a>
    <a class="main_links" href="#section_two/slide_one">2-1</a>
    <a class="main_links" href="#section_two/slide_two">2-2</a>
</div>

<section id="section_one">
    <div class="slide_holder">
        <div class="slide" id="section_one/slide_one"><p class="letters">1.1</p></div>
        <div class="slide" id="section_one/slide_two"><p class="letters">1.2</p></div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="section_two">
    <div class="slide_holder">
        <div class="slide" id="section_two/slide_one"><p class="letters">2.1</p></div>
        <div class="slide" id="section_two/slide_two"><p class="letters">2.2</p></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This example only uses css, so if you need to stop a slider plugin or go to a particular slide, you'll probably have to change this or even create a js function that is called when the respective anchor is called.

But you get the point, I guess.

Check the fiddle, tested on firefox and chrome on linux

https://jsfiddle.net/rymng1Lh/

I hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the exhaustive reply. i'll try asap and i'll let you know. Thanks again :)

Comment: There's a detail you are missing Brunofitas. FullPage.js doesn't work with `id` elements at all. It uses `data-anchor` tags instead. So the behavior and the problem here a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

fullPage.js doesn't provide a proper way to work with dynamic sections or slides at the moment.
You would need to replicate the structure used by it.

fullPage.js follows the following structure internally when dealing with slides within a section:

```
<div class="section fp-section" id="section1" data-anchor="secondPage" style="height: 925px; background-color: rgb(75, 191, 195);">
    <div class="fp-slides">
        <div class="fp-slidesContainer">
            <div class="slide fp-slide" style="width: 25%;">
              Slide 1
            </div>
            <div class="slide fp-slide" style="width: 25%;">
                Slide 2
            </div>
            <div class="slide fp-slide" style="width: 25%;">
                Slide 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fp-controlArrow fp-prev"></div>
    <div class="fp-controlArrow fp-next"></div>
</div>
```

You can easily check it by inspecting the DOM in [the demo page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage).

Note a few things:

- fullPage.js is using an internal class to identify the slides within a section, which is: `fp-slide`.
- It is also using two wrappers for the slides with the class `fp-slidesContainer` and `fp-slides`
- You would also have to add the `width`  in percentage depending on the number of slides that you have.
- There are two elements for each arrow (left and right)

Comment: thanks master for the reply, i was waiting for it :) i already inspected so well your demo page. Indeed, my php script now creates the fpslidesContainer div with "width: '.$slides*100).' %" and then the sldie fp-slide divs (with "width: '.(100/$slides).'%" .. but, even doing so, it doesnt work. It seems the page is not able to split anchors inside the page and inside a section. Divs are populated by a php script called by a js function.. i will try to populate divs with php directly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you update your question with the resulting HTML code generated with your PHP script?

Comment: thanks for your help! i edited the question with the section echoed by my php script

Comment: @sciakysystem you are not following the structure I mentioned. I don't see your `fp-slide` for each slide anywhere.